# netbeans and microsoft sql server connection exception

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, netbeans-7

I am trying to connect to my database, called "Recept". First I had some trouble about ports, but I fixed it. Now I have this code:

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;"
                + "databaseName=Recept;";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
        System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: " + cE.toString());
    }
```

And I get this exception:

```
SQL Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:01819eae-5044-426b-a462-645f247003d6
```

I don't know what my username and password is, this is how I can connect to my server, you can see, I don't need username and password:
[image]

Please someone help me, how should I write my "connectionUrl" in java?

Thank you!

Comment: Windows Authentication doesn't work in java code. You need to create a new user in the database and use this user to connect to the DB from java code.

Comment: and than how could I create a new user?

Comment: Actually, windows authentication will work if you load the authentication dll, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated

Comment: I can't understand it... I found the dll, but where should I copy the that file?? And than what should I write to my java "connectionUrl" code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the Windows Authentication with the SQL Server JDBC driver, you need to load the right authentication dll by adding the sqljdbc_auth.dll (32 bit or 64 bit depending on your JVM) on your java.library.path, and include the connection property `integratedSecurity=true` in the JDBC url.

See for detailed instruction and background http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated

Comment: I can't understand, where should I copy the dll? to: C:\Windows\System32? or where?

Comment: I copied it to C:\Windows\System32\, and than I got this exception:

`SQL Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. ClientConnectionId:f9ba4c34-194b-4a29-9805-c104624cb377`

Comment: 1) You shouldn't copy it in to system32, but simply set the java.library.path property to point to the location, 2) the error indicates that IntegratedSecurity is working, but most likely the application is running from a local account, for more info see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/05/03/understanding-the-error-message-login-failed-for-user-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can't you really work with JdbcOdbc driver?

```
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Recept","sa","sasasa");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```